# two numerical comparisons in one expression python

Tags: python, equality

I thought I read somewhere that python (3.x at least) is smart enough to handle this:

```
x = 1.01

if 1 < x < 0:
    print('out of range!')
```

However it is not working for me.

I know I can use this instead:

```
if ((x > 1) | (x < 0)):
    print('out of range!')
```

... but is it possible to fix the version above?

Comment: How can `1 < x < 0:` be True? Maybe `0 < x < 1`? We don't know what value you expect `x` to take.

Comment: @ roganjosh  `x = 1.01` ... first line. I wanted the print statement to be executed.

Comment: @n1k31t4: `1.01 < 0` is false.

Comment: I see now that I was a little hasty in asking for help. I learnt something nonetheless. I was still unclear whether the single expression is resolved with **and** / **or**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python chained comparisons work like mathematical notation. In math, "0 < x < 1" means that x is greater than 0 **and** less than one, and "1 < x < 0" means that x is greater than 1 **and** less than 0.

**And.** Not or. Both conditions need to hold.

If you want an "or" , you can write one yourself. It's `or` in Python, not `|`; `|` is bitwise OR.

```
if x > 1 or x < 0:
    whatever()
```

Alternatively, you can write your expression in terms of "and":

```
if not (0 <= x <= 1):
    whatever()
```

Comment: OP got away with the bitwise `or` because those are Boolean expressions.

Comment: @Prune: Yup, they got away with it, and that is the reason they got away with it, but they should still switch to the right operator.

Comment: Thanks - it was indeed the *and* part of the explanation which helped me see the light.

Answer (score 3):

It works well, it is your expression that is always False; try this one instead:

```
x = .99

if 1 > x > 0:
    print('out of range!')
```

Comment: I was just about to comment that :(. Still, here's the +1

Comment: Thanks for being the first answer, from which I worked out my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one *compound* expression, as you've already noted, and others have commented.  You cannot do it in an expression with an implied conjunction (and / or), as you're trying to do with `1 < x < 0`.  Your expression requires an `or` conjunction, but Python's implied operation in this case is `and`.

Therefore, to get what you want, you have to reverse your conditional branches and apply deMorgan's laws:

```
if not(0 <= x <= 1):
    print('out of range!')
```

Now you have the implied `and` operation, and you get the control flow you wanted.